# How to query woocommerce product by pricing?

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I've custom queried on my custom template, I want to show product by specific category with price range, like I've 10 products. Price is $10, $20, $15, $25 etc. Now I want to show that product low to high. Example 10, 15, 20, 25, like sorting system. 
Here is my query code. please share that code which code will i need to add with query code for show low to high.

```
<div class="combination-page fix">
    <div class="single-combination-area fix">

        <?php 
            $com_query = array(
                'post_type'     => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'product_cat' => 'combinations',                        
            );

        $comba = new WP_Query($com_query); 

        if($comba->have_posts()) : while($comba->have_posts()) : $comba->the_post();

            $com_size = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'combinations-size', true);
            $com_food_menus = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'combinations-food-menus', true);
        ?>
        <!--Single Combinations Product-->
        <div class="single-combination fix">
            <!--Single Combinations Product left-->
            <div class="single-com-image floatleft">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID())){

                     echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'com_product_img' );
                } else {
                    echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
                }
                ?>



                </a>
            </div><!--/ Single Combinations Product left-->

            <!--Single Combinations Product Right-->
            <div class="single-com-product-details floatleft">
                <!--Single Combinations Header-->
                <div class="single-com-header fix">
                    <div class="single-com-name fix">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ) ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                        <div class="single-com-price floatright">
                            <h2><span>Price : </span><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-com-info fix">
                        <?php if($com_size) : ?>
                        <div class="single-com-size">
                            <p><span> Size : </span><?php   echo $com_size; ; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/ Single Combinations Header-->

                <!-- Single Combinations description-->
                <div class="single-com-description">
                    <p><?php echo $product->post->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                </div><!--/ Single Combinations description-->

                <!-- Single Combinations Footer-->
                <div class="single-com-footer">
                    <div class="single-com-foodmenu floatleft">
                        <?php if($com_food_menus) : ?>
                        <ul>                            

                            <p>Food Menus: </p>

                            <?php foreach($com_food_menus as $food_menu) {
                            echo "<li>$food_menu</li>";

                            }
                        ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-com-addtocart floatright">                               
                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- / Single Combinations Footer-->
            </div><!--/ Single Combinations Product Right-->
        </div><!--/ Single Combinations Product-->

        <?php endwhile;  endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at the orderby parameter in wp_query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => '_price',
    'order'          => 'asc'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<form id="checkme">';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<div>';
    echo ' <input type="radio" name="products" value="'.get_the_title().'" >';
    echo '<label>' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    /*    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';*/
endwhile;
echo '</form>';
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Please explain how it solves the problem, as pure code dumps are not recommended without explanation, thanks.

Comment: WOW, Thanks for help, I just added extra
```'
orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => '_price',
    'order'          => 'asc'
```
then working fine. again thanks for help.